# Simplify hover Jquery sequential

Tags: jquery, list, hover, gallery, sequence

I have a gallery where I would like to hint that multiple items are on the same group by adding a class on hover

I achieved it by doing the following code I'm pretty sure it should be simpler but I'm still getting the handle of sequences so I can't get it to work so any help would be appreciated:

```
jQuery(".group1").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group1").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group1").removeClass( "tint" );});
jQuery(".group2").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group2").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group2").removeClass( "tint" );});
jQuery(".group3").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group3").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group3").removeClass( "tint" );});
jQuery(".group4").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group4").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group4").removeClass( "tint" );});
jQuery(".group5").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group5").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group5").removeClass( "tint" );});
```

Comment: please share the html also

Comment: do you have an typo here... in all cases you are changing the class of `group1`..

Comment: if you hover group2 do you want to change the class of group1 or group2

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, did have a typo when trying to simplify. I'll clean up html and paste some of it

Comment: then see my answer below options 3/4

Comment: mmmhh.. that doesn't work since multiple items need to highlight, updated your fiddle to show a better idea of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/nLd7P/3/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5DCV9/1/

Comment: Awesome! that worked, how do I mark your answer correct? Can you edit your original and add the code from jsfiddle?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer below... tick the tick mark at the top left corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a class group to all the element with class `group1` to `group5` then

```
jQuery(".group").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group1").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group1").removeClass( "tint" );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85DCs/)

---

If you don't want to do do that then use multiple selectors

```
jQuery(".group1, .group2, .group3, .group4, .group5").hover( 
    function() { jQuery(".group1").addClass( "tint" );}, 
    function() { jQuery(".group1").removeClass( "tint" );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TfNLK/)

---

But I think what you really want to do is to add/remove the tint class from the hovered element so

Add a class group to all the element with class `group1` to `group5` then

```
jQuery(".group").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass("tint");
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("tint");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K3fuN/)

---

or

```
jQuery(".group1, .group2, .group3, .group4, .group5").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass("tint");
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("tint");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nLd7P/)

---

**Update**

```
<div class="group group1">group1</div>
<div class="group group2">group2</div>
<div class="group group1">group1</div>
<div class="group group3">group3</div>
<div class="group group4">group4</div>
<div class="group group4">group4</div>
<div class="group group5">group5</div>
<div class="group group1">group1</div>
<div class="group group2">group2</div>
<div class="group group3">group3</div>
<div class="group group3">group3</div>
<div class="group group3">group3</div>
<div class="group group4">group4</div>
<div class="group group5">group5</div>
```

then

```
jQuery('.group').hover(function () {
    jQuery('.' + this.className.match(/(group\d+)/)[1]).addClass("tint");
}, function () {
    jQuery('.' + this.className.match(/(group\d+)/)[1]).removeClass("tint");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X9Nfy/)

Comment: Thanks! working with digits will be my weekend homework!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you always apply on group1, I would suggest that :

```
$.each([ ".group1", ".group2", ".group3", ".group4", ".group5" ], 
  function( index, value ) {
   $(value).hover( 
      function() { $(".group1").addClass( "tint" );}, 
      function() { $(".group1").removeClass( "tint" );}
   );
});
```

Else replace ".group1" by value

Comment: Thanks @yoann , sorry it was a typo so you don't always apply it to group 1. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use genetic way to do the job.

please look this example I made

```
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group"> </div>
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group"></div>
```

css:

```
.tint{
    background:black;
}

.group{
    width:100px;
        height:100px;
        margin:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

js:

```
$('.group').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('tint')
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('tint');
});
```

please see jsfiddle case:
http://jsfiddle.net/p6ULb/1/

---

**Update**
So if the class name is group1...group5 you can work in following way.

js

```
var arr=["group1","group2","group3","group4","group5"]
arr=arr.map(function(item){
    return "."+item;
});

console.log(arr);
$(arr.join(",")).hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('tint')
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('tint');
});
```

case jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/p6ULb/2/

Comment: Thanks @caogish, sorry I had a typo and edit it. Don't think I would even need jQuery if they were all targeting the same group (css :hover)

Comment: the point here is not only change css, but also change something else in js. if you can do some in CSS, you should. but some only can be done in js, then use js.

Comment: if you want to solve the group1 ... group2 I also have updated solution for you.